# Errors after re-index: Item (Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite) with the same id "0" already exist"

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

we did a complete re-index of our store. The core_url_rewrite table is full with around 288,000 entries. We have just over 40,000 Products and 6 StoreViews defined, with 5 currently being active.

However, the front end gives us 404 errors for SEO friendly urls.

In the backend, if I try to have a look at Catalog -> Rewrite URL Management, I receive the following error:

```
"Item (Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite) with the same id "0" already exist"
```

When I check the core_url_rewrite table, all the url_rewrite_id's are 0!
I would have thought these would auto_increment?

**I think the the DB Table was create wrongly without any auto-increment!**

```
a:5:{i:0;s:69:"Item (Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite) with the same id "0" already exist";i:1;s:4054:"#0 /html/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(576): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite))
#1 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#2 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Grid.php(48): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#3 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Urlrewrite_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#4 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#5 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#6 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#8 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#9 /html/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#10 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/html/magento/a...')
#11 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#12 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#16 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#18 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#20 /html/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#21 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/html/magento/a...')
#22 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#23 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#24 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/UrlrewriteController.php(74): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_UrlrewriteController->indexAction()
#30 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#31 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#32 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#33 /html/magento/app/Mage.php(699): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#34 /html/magento/index.php(98): Mage::run('', 'store')
#35 {main}";s:3:"url";s:77:"/index.php/admin/admin/urlrewrite/index/key/78b5386c722edee4e716f0c81bb03114/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can fix this?

If a fix is possible without a complete re-index that would be grand!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I check the core_url_rewrite table, all the url_rewrite_id's are 0! These should AUTO_INCREMENT.

So the the DB Table was create wrongly without any auto-increment!

I have to delete and re-create the table with AUTO_INCREMENT.

here are the table details:

WRONG:

```
CREATE TABLE `core_url_rewrite` (
  `url_rewrite_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Rewrite Id',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `id_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Id Path',
  `request_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Request Path',
  `target_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Target Path',
  `is_system` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Defines is Rewrite System',
  `options` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Options',
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Deascription',
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Category Id',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id'
) TYPE=InnoDB COMMENT='Url Rewrites';
```

RIGHT SHOULD BE:

```
CREATE TABLE `core_url_rewrite` (
  `url_rewrite_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Rewrite Id',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `id_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Id Path',
  `request_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Request Path',
  `target_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Target Path',
  `is_system` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Defines is Rewrite System',
  `options` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Options',
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Deascription',
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Category Id',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
  PRIMARY KEY (`url_rewrite_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID` (`request_path`,`store_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID` (`id_path`,`is_system`,`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_TARGET_PATH_STORE_ID` (`target_path`,`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH` (`id_path`),
  KEY `IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  KEY `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` (`category_id`),
  KEY `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Url Rewrites';
```

To avoid re-indexing I copied the values from the wrong table to the new excluding the id value using:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO _core_url_rewrite (store_id, id_path, request_path, target_path, is_system, options, description, category_id, product_id)
SELECT Distinct store_id, id_path, request_path, target_path, is_system, options, description, category_id, product_id
FROM core_url_rewrite
```

Then I removed the wrong table and renamed the correct table. Now all is working fine.

=)

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate var/locks directory and remove all files under this directory. This will clear all the locks for re-indexing to take place again.
2. Now, login to your MysQSL/phpMyAdmin to run the following MySQL query (Ensure that your have taken full backup before committing this MySQL query)

   DELETE cpop.* FROM catalog_product_option_price AS cpop
   INNER JOIN catalog_product_option AS cpo
   ON cpo.option_id = cpop.option_id
   WHERE
   cpo.type = 'checkbox' OR
   cpo.type = 'radio' OR
   cpo.type = 'drop_down';

   DELETE cpotp.* FROM catalog_product_option_type_price AS cpotp
   INNER JOIN catalog_product_option_type_value AS cpotv
   ON cpotv.option_type_id = cpotp.option_type_id
   INNER JOIN catalog_product_option AS cpo
   ON cpotv.option_id = cpo.option_id
   WHERE
   cpo.type <> 'checkbox' AND
   cpo.type <> 'radio' AND
   cpo.type <> 'drop_down';
3. Log back in to your Magento Admin panel and go to System tab > Index Management hit index again and you will notice no such errors will appear again. You can follow these same steps again if re-indexing stops in future to resolve Magento ReIndexing issues.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, however this will not fix my problem, as the table core_url_rewrite seems to have been created without an AUTO_INCREMENT, thus all url_rewrite_id = 0 iunstead of increasing 1,2,3, etc ..